# How to send a Parcelable object to a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, parcelable

I'm able to send my data from `Activity1` to `Activity2` with the typical..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("state", getIntent().getParcelableExtra("state"));
intent.putExtra("schools", temp);
startActivity(intent);
```

and that works fine once I'm at the `Activity2`, the issue is how to make it work from `Activity1` to a `DialogFragment`? How do you send the parcelable objects and retrieve them once I'm coding the `DialogFragment`? Any example available out there you can point me at?

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog) can help.
Basically by using `setArguments()` and later `getArguments()` in the Dialog's `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle to pass Parcelable object to your DialogFragment.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

(EDIT:)

Let's say you need a TimePicker DialogFragment somewhere in your Activity1:

```
// This is a static inner class which resides inside your Activity1
// so you will face this limitation :
// You can only access static method from inside this. You also can
// not remove static keyword or you will face memory leak.

public static class StartTimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

static StartTimePickerFragment newInstance (int arg, YourParcelableObj obj) {

        StartTimePickerFragment DialogFrag = new 
            StartTimePickerFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("Whatever", arg);
        // for Parcelable :
        args.putParcelable ("Whatever2", obj);
        DialogFrag.setArguments(args);
        return DialogFrag;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("whatever");
}

 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            // now here you can not directly access class methods and
            // and data members. so get the Activity object and then
            // you are good to 'set/get' them here in  your
            // DialogFragment

            Activity1 activity = (Activity1) getActivity();
            activity.your_non_static_method(hourOfDay, minute);
            activity.your_non_static_activitidy_member_Data = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of content around the link.  In other words, provide an answer to the question, using the link only as a reference for a *fuller treatment* of your answer.  The reason for this on SO is just in case a link goes bad.  If that happens in the case of this answer, future users of SO would have nothing to go on.